# Search an Array by all the properties

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Users are allowed to search their data by keying Name or City or Code. How can I display matched object  on the top of the dropdown list.

Prioritizing `Code` here as when user enters `JOH` the following obj will be highlighted.

```
{
  name: 'John Cena',
  code: 'JOH',
  city: 'California'
}
```

Below code works only if user enters the full name or code or city. The list has over 1000 records.

Trying to match the 3 characters `code` first with that of user input or otherwise by name or city.

```
let input = e.currentTarget.value;
const arr = []
  for (const user of List) {
    if (user.code.includes(input) > -1) {
          arr.push(station)
        }
    
  }
}
```

Comment: *Below code works only if I enter in full* - full what?

Comment: I meant when user enters at least  5 to 6 characters then the filter takes place displaying the matching object. The code has just 3 characters so I am trying to match code with that of user input.

Comment: `user.code.toLowerCase().includes(input) || user.city.toLowerCase().includes(input) || user.name.toLowerCase().includes(input)`

Comment: Your code will also find an input of `joh`, but there is no form of priorization what soever. So the matches are just returned in the order they appear in the `userList`

Comment: I would use a fuzzy search library like [fuse.js](https://fusejs.io/)

Comment: `includes` returns `true` or `false` comparing it to `1` doesn't make sense. `if (user.code.includes(input))` is enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you also need some sort of priorization (ie a match in `code` counts more than a match in `name`) you will need to weigh each match and then sort by weight. Assuming `userList` is an array

```
let results = userList.map(user => {
     let weight = 0;
     if (user.code.toLowerCase().includes(input)) weight = 900
     else if (user.name.toLowerCase().includes(input)) weight = 800
     else if (user.city.toLowerCase().includes(input)) weight = 700

     return { user, weight };
   })
   .filter(x => x.weight > 0)
   .sort((a,b) => b.weight - a.weight)
   .map(x => x.user);
```

This will return a list of users sorted by the best match (ie match by `code`) first. It's not super efficent, as it's traversing the list multiple times, but actually I don't think this will be a real issue at just 1000 elements ...

If you run into performance issues, you could for instance refactor `userlist.map(...).filter(...)` into `userlist.reduce()` but I leave that up to you ... For understanding the solution, I think `map` and `filter` are easier to read.

Comment: I like the `weight` idea here... +1

Comment: Tested your solution [here](https://codepen.io/Bes7weB/pen/poZrzyq?editors=0012) ;) I suggest you use it to add a snippet.

Comment: And if I just filter first 20 list based on every key stroke i.e. if results?.length >= 20 break.

Comment: .map(x => x.user).slice(0,20); will give the best results. Thank you.